# Implementing pointers in program

Tags: c

I've written a program to ask for the user inputs for numbers of cents and prints out the type of coins that make up that amount.

I'm trying to learn about pointers, and I would like to include the following in my program:

```
void coins(int cents, int *quarters, int *dimes, int *nickels, int *pennies);
```

I would appreciate it if someone could teach me implement this in my program

```
#include 
#define QUARTER 25
#define DIME 10
#define NICKEL 5
#define PENNY 1

int main()
{
        //initialize variables and read input
        int cents, pennies, quarters, dimes, nickels;
        pennies = quarters = dimes = nickels =0;
        printf("Enter the number of cents:\n");
        scanf("%d", ¢s);

        //check the range of the input amount
        if(cents< 0 || cents > 10000)
           printf("Invalid amount %d,\nAmount must be between 0 and 10000, inclusive\n", cents);
        else {
                quarters = cents/QUARTER;
                dimes = cents%QUARTER/DIME;
                nickels = cents%QUARTER%DIME/NICKEL;
                pennies = cents%QUARTER%DIME%NICKEL;

                printf("Quarters: %d\n", quarters);
                printf("Dimes: %d\n", dimes);
                printf("Nickels: %d\n", nickels);
                printf("Pennies: %d\n", pennies);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", ¢s);` --> expect `scanf("%d", &cents);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include it with some correction

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define QUARTER 25
#define DIME 10
#define NICKEL 5
#define PENNY 1

void coins(int cents, int *quarters, int *dimes, int *nickels, int *pennies);

int main(void)
{
        //initialize variables and read input
        int cents, pennies, quarters, dimes, nickels;
        pennies = quarters = dimes = nickels =0;
        printf("Enter the number of cents:\n");
        scanf("%d", &cents);

        //check the range of the input amount
        if(cents< 0 || cents > 10000)
           printf("Invalid amount %d,\nAmount must be between 0 and 10000, inclusive\n", cents);
        else {
                quarters = cents/QUARTER;
                dimes = cents%QUARTER/DIME;
                nickels = cents%QUARTER%DIME/NICKEL;
                pennies = cents%QUARTER%DIME%NICKEL;

                printf("Quarters: %d\n", quarters);
                printf("Dimes: %d\n", dimes);
                printf("Nickels: %d\n", nickels);
                printf("Pennies: %d\n", pennies);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

or make some use of it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define QUARTER 25
#define DIME 10
#define NICKEL 5
#define PENNY 1

void coins(int cents, int *quarters, int *dimes, int *nickels, int *pennies);

int main(void)
{
        //initialize variables and read input
        int cents, pennies, quarters, dimes, nickels;
        pennies = quarters = dimes = nickels =0;
        printf("Enter the number of cents:\n");
        scanf("%d", &cents);

        //check the range of the input amount
        if(cents< 0 || cents > 10000)
           printf("Invalid amount %d,\nAmount must be between 0 and 10000, inclusive\n", cents);
        else {
                coins(cents, &quarters, &dimes, &nickels, &pennies);

                printf("Quarters: %d\n", quarters);
                printf("Dimes: %d\n", dimes);
                printf("Nickels: %d\n", nickels);
                printf("Pennies: %d\n", pennies);
        }
        return 0;
}

void coins(int cents, int *quarters, int *dimes, int *nickels, int *pennies)
{
        *quarters = cents/QUARTER;
        *dimes = cents%QUARTER/DIME;
        *nickels = cents%QUARTER%DIME/NICKEL;
        *pennies = cents%QUARTER%DIME%NICKEL;
}
```